# how to convert row in column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, db2

i have table employee

```
+------+-----------+
| name | is_active |
+------+-----------+
|  a   |         0 |
|  b   |         1 |
|  c   |         1 |
|  d   |         1 |
|  e   |         0 |
+------+-----------+
```

when we use query

```
select   is_active, count(*) count 
from     employee 
group by is_active;
```

then output in form of

```
+-----------+--------+
| is_active |  count |
+-----------+--------+
|         1 |      3 |
|         0 |      2 |
+-----------+--------+
```

but i want to output in that form

```
+-----------+---+----+
| is_active | 0 |  1 |
+-----------+---+----+
| count     | 2 |  3 |
+-----------+---+----+
```

Comment: `MySQL` or `DB2`...?

Comment: ... rotate the printed report 90%?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse -- ... lay on your side?

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select 'count' as is_active,
    count(case when is_active = 0 then 1 end) as count_0,
    count(case when is_active = 1 then 1 end) as count_1
from t;
```

In MySQL, you can write this using `sum`:

```
select 'count' as is_active,
    sum(is_active = 0) as count_0,
    sum(is_active = 1) as count_1
from t;
```